# Should I backup my drivers when upgrading OS to 8?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8, drivers, backup

I am upgrading from XP to 8 and I was wondering if there was a tool that I can use that will create a backup of my drivers if I need them again and if this is even necessary and I can just use a program such as Slimdrivers.

**So, is it necessary to do this or is it just wasting time? If I should do it, what tool should I use?** (The computer I'm upgrading doesn't have a CD drive because it's a netbook, so no CD backup. However, I will be using an external for files. Also, I'm using the $40 upgrade, so I cannot partition it to get it later if necessary.)

---

**Specs:**

Acer Aspire One ZG5 (2009, XP)

1 GB RAM

1.6 GHz Processor

[Some More Specs](http://gdgt.com/acer/aspire/one/zg5/specs/)

(I really don't know much more than above, if you want me to look up something I can.)

Connected Items:

External USB Keyboard/Mouse (Have model numbers for drivers)

USB Hub

Speakers (Model # Again, Logitech so not hard to find)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows XP and Windows 8 are very different operating systems under the hood.  XP drivers are not going to work with Windows 8.  However, Windows 8 should work on most modern computers.  Windows 8 should automatically detect and install most, if not all, if the drivers for you.  In some cases you might need to download the Windows 8 specific drivers from the manufacturers website.

Run the Windows 8 [Upgrade Assistant](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8) to see if any of your hardware is incompatible.  Most likely, you will not have any issues.

Comment: @anonomous, I'd agree with the above. The only concern would be the wireless card depending on the chipset, but the upgrade assistant should help there. On a side note, you're at the very limit of the hardware requirements and I'm not convinced Win 8 will run that well. I'd do a quick search to see how others have found it on the same hardware if you haven't purchased Win 8 already. If the report is poor, consider putting the money towards a new/used laptop.

Comment: @archery1234 I looked it up. One even ran it considerably well with a *1/2 gig* of ram. I watched some YouTube videos, and they are better/the same as what I have now as far as responding to cliks (very low end laptop; cheap budget) with similar specs.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson, there a low end laptops and there are Netbooks with single core atom processors. Even the cheapest of the crop of current laptops will have a budget dual core processor and 2GB RAM. I had Win XP on a similar Asus 1000 with 2GB of RAM and performance was just about OK. I suppose it's all relative and depends what you're use to. There are users with Atom processors who've said performance is OK but they seem to be running 2GB of RAM.

Comment: @archery1234 1 Its for basic browsing and I have lots of tricks up my sleeve for speeding it up. It does have a intel processor though…

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think it mainly depends on the hardware you're using.
Unless you have some sort of old hardware (a very old printer, web camera, WiFi adapter etc.), I think it would be safe to just upgrade. Windows 8 itself has tons of built-in drivers and most hardware should be recognized pretty well.

If you're not sure, I guess that you could post your system specs here and we'll let you know whether you should worry about drivers or not.

Comment: Added some specs.

Answer (score -4):

Upgrade to Windows 8

Before upgrading to Windows 8, we recommend that you run the Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant. It scans your current PC to see if it is ready for Windows 8 and then provides a compatibility report and optional steps for you to buy, download, and install Windows 8.

To learn more about how we use your info, read the Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant privacy statement.

If you upgrade to Windows 8 and want to go back to your previous version of Windows, you’ll need the recovery or installation media that came with your PC from the PC manufacturer. For more info, see the Support section of this page.

Before upgrading to Windows 8, we recommend that you visit your PC manufacturer's website for info about updated drivers and hardware compatibility.
Redeeming a special offer

If you have an offer code you need to make sure that you enter it to receive the promotional price. When you're on the Buy screen, it will show the full price. However, on the order confirmation page you'll have a chance to enter your promo code then the price will change to reflect the offer promotional price after you click Apply.

If your PC is currently running Windows 7, your files, apps, and settings will easily transfer toWindows 8. If your PC is running Windows XP or Windows Vista, you'll need to reinstall your apps after you upgrade.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8

Comment: you just.. copy pasted from MS's site. Twice. Maybe 3 times. I'm not even sure.